# 「簡単に外部RSSをサイトに表示できるGoogle Feed API【複数RSS対応編】」のコードが Cordova 4.1 にして動かなくなりました

Tags: monaca, cordova

「[簡単に外部RSSをサイトに表示できるGoogle Feed API【複数RSS対応編】](http://news.7zz.jp/ajax/2447.html)」で紹介されているコードをほぼそのまま使わせてもらって Monaca で複数の RSS を読み込むアプリを製作して公開していましたが Cordova 2.9を使用していたため 4.1 に切り替えたところ、 デバッガーでは全て読み込んでくれますがビルドすると HTML 部分とスプラッシュスクリーンしか表示されなくなりました。

「Monaca Cordova 3.5 移行ガイド」の「config.xmlの形式の変更による影響」や「[18-5.Cordovaの脆弱性問題（バージョンアップしたら音が出ないよ編）](http://easyapp.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-261.html)」 の「エクスポート＆インポート」も試してみたのですが、上手く行かず。

なにやら雲を掴むような説明で申し訳ないですが、
解決のヒントを戴ければ幸いです。

Comment: 本文に合わせて、タイトルを 「Cordova 4.1 にして動かなくなりました」 から 「「簡単に外部RSSをサイトに表示できるGoogle Feed API【複数RSS対応編】」のコードが Cordova 4.1 にして動かなくなりました」 に変更しました。問題あれば元に戻してください。コードやログの報告がありませんので、原因は Cordova 4.1 対応以外にも、色々と考えられるかと思います。

Comment: 移行ガイドにて既にご存知かと思いますが、2.9から4.1への移行は、ソースコードの大きな変更が必要となります。ソースコードの変更が大きく、修正箇所が判断できない場合は、現在も動いているアプリであればそのままの方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

Monacaで新しくRSSリーダーテンプレートにてプロジェクトを作成して、ビルドすると動きました。動作したコードが以下です。お役に立てると嬉しいです。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // 初期設定
        var disp_entry_count = 8;       //表示させたい記事の数

        // RSS URL
        var site = new Array();

        site[0] = { 
            title:'GIZUMODO',
            url:'http://feeds.gizmodo.jp/rss/gizmodo/index.xml',
            disp_entry:2        // 取得する記事の数
        };

        site[1] = { 
            title:'Gigazin',
            url:'http://feed.rssad.jp/rss/gigazine/rss_2.0',
            disp_entry:3        // 取得する記事の数
        };

        site[2] = {            
            title:'ウェブソク',
            url:'http://news.7zz.jp/feed',
            disp_entry:5        // 取得する記事の数
        };

        var channel = new Array();
        var entry = new Array();
        var entries = new Array();
        var Feed = "";

        google.load("feeds", "1");
        function init() {

            var site_count = 0;

            for (var i=0; i<site.length; i++){

                // 読み込むRSSを設定
                var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(site[i]['url']);
                feed.setNumEntries(site[i]['disp_entry'])
                feed.load(function(rss) {
                    if (!rss.error) {

                        // RSSからサイトの情報を配列に格納
                        channel['title'] = rss.feed.title;
                        channel['link'] = rss.feed.link;
                        channel['favicon'] = "http://favicon.hatena.ne.jp/?url=" + channel['link'];
                        channel['description'] = rss.feed.description;
                        channel['author'] = rss.feed.author;

                        // RSSから記事の情報を配列に格納
                        for (var j=0; j<rss.feed.entries.length; j++){

                            var feed_entry = rss.feed.entries[j];
                            var entry = {
                                site_title : channel['title'],
                                site_link : channel['link'],
                                site_favicon : channel['favicon'],
                                title : feed_entry.title,
                                link : feed_entry.link,
                                content : feed_entry.content,
                                contentSnippet : feed_entry.contentSnippet,
                                publishedDate : feed_entry.publishedDate
                            };

                            var date = new Date(entry['publishedDate']);
                            entry['time'] = date.getTime();
                            var yy = date.getYear();
                            var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
                            var dd = date.getDate();
                            if (yy < 2000) { yy += 1900; }
                            if (mm < 10) { mm = "0" + mm; }
                            if (dd < 10) { dd = "0" + dd; }
                            entry['date'] = yy + "年" + mm + "月" + dd + "日";

                            entry['img'] = entry['content'].match(/src="(.*?)"/igm);

                            if (entry['img'] != null) {
                                for (var k=0; k<entry['img'].length; k++){
                                    entry['img'][k] = entry['img'][k].replace(/src=/ig, "");
                                    entry['img'][k] = entry['img'][k].replace(/"/ig, "");
                                }
                            }
                            entries.push(entry);
                        }
                    }
                    site_count++;
                    if (site.length == site_count){ disp(); }
                });
            }
        }

        function disp() {

            //日付順に並べ替え
            entries.sort (function (b1, b2) { return b1.time < b2.time ? 1 : -1; } );

            // 記事をhtmlに整形
            for (var l=0; l<disp_entry_count; l++){
                if (entries.length < l+1){ break; }

                if (entries[l]['img'] != null) { Feed += '<img width="100" src="' + entries[l]['img'][0] + '">n'; }
                Feed += '<h2><img src="' + entries[l]['site_favicon'] + '">n'
                            + 'n'
                            + '<a href="' + entries[l]['site_link'] + '">' + entries[l]['site_title'] + '</a></h2>n'
                            + entries[l]['date']
                            + '<h3>n'
                            + '<a href="'+ entries[l]['link'] + '">' + entries[l]['title'] + '</a>n'
                            + '</h3>n'
                            + '<p>contentSnippet:' + entries[l]            ['contentSnippet'].substr(0, 100) + '……</p>nn';
            }
            // 表示するタグに追加
            $('#topics').append( Feed );
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1>Google AJAX Feed API　複数ブログの場合</h1>
       <!-- RSSを表示するタグ -->
       <div id="topics"></div>
       </body>
     </html>
```